# Refused to frame 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy: "frame-ancestors 'none'"

Tags: php, iframe, payment-gateway, content-security-policy

Integrate santander credit card payment gateway integration issue:

I take code from this link: https://desarrolladores.santandertpv.es/conexion-insite.html (below section: Solicitud de la operación)

I add this code in an online demo to show the error
Demo link:

- https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/y233ddd7f
  https://jsonformatter.org/html-viewer/e8d41d

Please open the browser console to see the error.

**Error**:
**Refused to frame 'https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".**

Is the problem exist on https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443 ? OR we can do anything?

I tried code provided in the official documentation but got an error.

I tried adding header in the apache, nginx server like:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443;"
```

Comment: Hi. I'm in the same exact situation as you are tho with BBVA instead of Santander. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, It seems Santander do not allow. Needs to ask them to whitelist ip.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing today. It's a shame you can't alter the whitelisted domains yourself. Anyway, thanks a ton for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You MUST contact Redsys Support and ask them to add your domain / subdomain in the "list of accepted domains for InSite". Once they have added it in, it will show up in the Admin page under Administracion (icono maletin) > Comercio > Datos de Configuracion > Dominios InSite Permitidos.

You can probably not enable this yourself, so you need support to do this for you.

Once you leave the Testing Environment and move to the Real Environment, you will need to add the domains again.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the requests and responses in the codebeautify.com example above you will see that the response to https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/getInputNC?... sets "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors ;" and consequently will not allow to be framed by anyone. The request to https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/NC/sandbox/redsysV3.js does not set the a CSP or X-Frame-Options to block framing.

This likely means that the resource doesn't allow framing, or must be configured differently to include your site in the list of allowed framers.